# Random Integers of int elements in Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, random

Please guys, I am still learning Java and not familiar with some of its iteration techniques yet. I want to iterate through this array int[] lst = {34, 23, 7, 14, 10} so that it must generate random numbers between each elements in the array. Eg. It must be able to list random values between 34 and 23, 23 and 7, 7 and 14, and 14 and 10.
Please I need help terribly as I have been working for it ever since last night till morning. My terrible code is pasted below.

```
public class ArrayRange {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] lst = {34, 23, 7, 14, 10};
        for(int i = 0; i < lst.length; i++){
            if ( i == 0){
                int result = rand.nextInt(lst[i])+1;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            else {
                int max = lst.length - 1;
                System.out.println(rand.nextInt(max - lst[i])+ 1);
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Two key things to consider. If you want `[i]` and `[i+1]`, then loop to `lst.length - 1`. For the random number, you will want a number in difference between two elements added to the first.

Comment: How many values in each range?

Comment: @KevinO you are correct but he doesn't have `lst[i+1]` anywhere in his code

Comment: @JackVanier, Yes, the OP does not, but in a straight iteration it would be easier than writing special test case code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class ArrayRange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] lst = {34, 23, 7, 14, 10};
        for(int i = 0; i < lst.length-1; i++){
            int val = rand.nextInt(Math.max(lst[i], lst[i+1]) - Math.min(lst[i], lst[i+1])) + Math.min(lst[i], lst[i+1]);
            System.out.println("(" + lst[i] + ", " + lst[i+1] + "):" + val);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but iti didn't work. It displays the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at SumNum.main(ArrayRange.java:6)

Comment: I'm sorry! , thanks very much, It gives me the idea afterwards